# SQl query inner join to return the available data even if the join is missing

Tags: sql

I am still messing around with this query, which is working but is not returning the data I need.

```
SELECT     prod.Code,
           prod.Description,
           prod.Groupp,
           prod.Quantity,
           prod.Unit,
           prod.Standard,
           prod.Type,
           prod.Model,
           prod.GroupBKM,
           prod.Note,
           comp.Unit,
           comp.Cost

FROM           dbo.Product1 prod    
INNER JOIN     dbo.Components comp
ON             comp.Code = prod.Code
```

The above query is returning the data only if a comp.code=prod.code exists while I would like to get the data prod.* in any case and obviously the data relevant comp.cost, if does not exist,  will be null.
I cannot get it right! Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Thanks. Finally is returning something! Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace `INNER JOIN` with `LEFT JOIN`

```
SELECT     prod.Code,
           prod.Description,
           prod.Groupp,
           prod.Quantity,
           prod.Unit,
           prod.Standard,
           prod.Type,
           prod.Model,
           prod.GroupBKM,
           prod.Note,
           comp.Unit,
           comp.Cost

FROM           dbo.Product1 prod    
LEFT JOIN     dbo.Components comp
ON             comp.Code = prod.Code
```

Comment: Is the good one and I will accept it. Howevwer thanks to Helmeg who gave the correct comment first.

Answer (score 2):

By definition you **cannot** do this with an `INNER JOIN` because an `INNER JOIN` is defined as only returning items for which a match was found.

If you want to return rows in the base `SELECT` even if the `JOIN` predicate fails, then you want a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` ... which is defined as precisely that.

Answer (score 1):

From Wikipedia:

> An outer join does not require each record in the two joined tables to
>   have a matching record. The joined table retains each record—even if
>   no other matching record exists. Outer joins subdivide further into
>   left outer joins, right outer joins, and full outer joins, depending
>   on which table's rows are retained (left, right, or both).

In your case, replace `INNER JOIN` with `LEFT OUTER JOIN`.